# How to compress multiple folders, each into its own zip archive?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, terminal

So I want to create a script that enables me to compresses each folder into its own zip 
archive and not into a one big zip file.

As an example, I've got a directory:

```
+ MyDirectory/
| |
| + Folder_01/
| |
| + Folder_02/
| |
| + Folder_03/
|
```

When I'm done running the script under `MyDirectory` then I would have a zip file of each Folder which is inside `MyDirectory`: `Folder_01.zip`, `Folder_02.zip` and `Folder_03.zip`.
I know some BASH but this is something I can't figure out.

How can this be done?

Kind regards.

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi @EdHeal, I knew I needed to do some strange bash for loop with variables and when it comes to variables and for loops in bash I'm stuck. But I finally found an answer [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68489/command-to-zip-multiple-directories-into-individual-zip-files) to my question. I think I will save the code into an executable and store it under bin/ folder because I think bash scripting like that just confusing.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

```
for i in *
do
[ -d "$i" ] && zip -r "$i.zip" "$i"
done
```

You walk through all the directories and create zip for each of them.

Or even more concise:

```
for i in */; do zip -r "${i%/}.zip" "$i"; done
```

(thanks to damienfrancois for suggestion).

Comment: you can avoid the `[ -d "$i" ] && ` part with `for i in */`

Comment: @damienfrancois: Superhint! Thank you!!

Comment: though you have to `${i%/}.zip` afterwards to get rid of the trailing `/` in this particular case

Comment: Thank you! If making this an executable to store under bin/ directory and to useful to do compression operations where you'd provide options like `*/` for directories, or `*.*` for files, or even `*.jpeg` if you only want to compress .jpeg files. How would you write the code so that you'd only need to type f.ex. `compress */`, or `compress *.jpeg`? To take it even further the script could be written so that you could provide options like `-a/--all` for compressing all into one big zip archive, and `-e/--each` for compressing each into its own zip file, etc... Thank you! :)

Comment: @VilliMagg: That's right, but you must note that it is the shell who expands file globs, so your script will not get all these `*.jpeg` etc unless you escape them with ''

Comment: @IgorChubin: So it would be necessary to type `compress "*.jpeg"`?

Comment: @VilliMagg: Yes, if you want script to get the star and the expanded list.

Comment: @damienfrancois - Great 1-liner: `for i in */; do zip -r "${i%/}.zip" "$i"; done` It works when I tested on mobaxterm v11 (after installing zip utility) in windows 10. Thank you!

Comment: @IgorChubin how can i give them password , same or a different

Comment: @Becauseihatemyself `zip -p PASSWORD ...`

Answer (score 12):

here

```
for i in */; do tar -czvf "${i%/}.tar.gz" "$i"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [`xz`](http://catchchallenger.first-world.info//wiki/Quick_Benchmark:_Gzip_vs_Bzip2_vs_LZMA_vs_XZ_vs_LZ4_vs_LZO) algorithm if you require smaller output (at the cost of longer process):

```
for d in */ ; do
    outName=$d;
    outName=${outName// /\-};
    outName=${outName//[!0-9a-z-]};
    dirName=$d;
    dirName=${dirName//\/}
    tar -c "$dirName" | xz -e > $outName.tar.xz
done
```

This code will sanitise folder names and produce `.tar.xz` for every folder in the current directory.

Comment: You might want to add a note that `-e` increases the time for compression significantly and should more or less only be used for archiving.

Answer (score 0):

I take the old solutions and get back with another good solution that works for any directory in any place in you drive

This code in Bash

```
#!/bin/bash

folderPath=/home/ahmed/test/

for folder in $folderPath*
do
        folderName=$(basename $folder)
        cd $folderPath && zip -r $folderName.zip $folderName
done
```

So all folders inside **test** folder will be zipped in the same folder

Comment: this doesn't work at all

Answer (score 0):

I personally use

`fd . -t d -x zip -r '{}.zip' '{}'`

(`fd` might be `fd-find` depending on your OS)

Comment: your command created an zip file for every subdir on my laptop, is it really correct?